# xcode instrument points to NSZombie in main ( )

Tags: exc-bad-access, xcode-instruments

I have been fighting EXC_BAD_ACCESS problem on the device, and finally was able to dup the problem in the simulator. I used NSZombie in Instruments and it points to code in main.m as shown below in the screenshots.

I am confused as to what can cause this and what the solution would be.  The app is a tabBarController-based app.  The third tab is a navController, with 3 VCs. The first two VCs are tableViewController.  Tapping a row in the first VC leads to the table in the second VC.  When the table in the second VC has number of rows > screenful and I scroll to the bottom to look at an entry.  The crash happens when, next, I return to the first VC using the navController's Back button.  I hope I am making sense...

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

Comment: search for __unsafe_unretained vars, otherwise ARC should correctly manage the memory.

Comment: I *am* using ARC - and that's what is bothering me....

Comment: I think it will print out the class name of the Zombie object which should be useful.